# Make emoji color greyscale

Tags: flutter

How can I make an emoji grayscale? I tried the following but it gives the entire container a grey background: [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/a3bdd5f6dba7a6cb481ac21a9368e8b6)

```
 Container(
  foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation),
  child: Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))),
);
```

Comment: Your code works well on Android but probably not on Web

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColorFiltered class instead. Please check the code below. Note the ClipOval is optional and you may supply a circle customclipper.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipOval(
      child: 
        ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey, BlendMode.color),
        child: Text(
          '',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 50,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```